# Jetty MultipartFormDataInput not being dispatched

Tags: java, jboss, jetty, resteasy, multipartform-data

I'm developing a Jetty Servlet, which should be used for uploading a file and some parameters, but the MultipartFormDataInput throws an exception. But the jetty webserver starts as expected so far.

The code looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void createApp(MultipartFormDataInput ressources, @Suspended AsyncResponse response);
```

When a request calles this servlet, following exception is being thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.DefaultStorageProvider
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.initializeClass(Loader.java:285) ~[log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:500) ~[log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:621) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:146) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:323) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.serialize(Log4jLogEvent.java:429) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender.append(AsyncAppender.java:153) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:97) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:428) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:407) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:365) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112) [log4j-core-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.log(Log4jLogger.java:374) [log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:607) [jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.warn(JettyAwareLogger.java:431) [jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:69) [jetty-util-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:667) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
```

If i remove the MultipartFormDataInput param, everything works as expected. What is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**

Thereafter there is an other output message:

```
2016-01-26 13:20:00,152 WARN  [pool-2-thread-15] ? (:) - badMessage: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp@46c1358f{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is my maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please share your client code? I'm having similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is telling you that your slf4j + log4j setup is not configured properly.

Something in your setup is attempting to emit logs to an appender that needs a functioning `org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.DefaultStorageProvider` class.

This class can't initialize for some reason.  There should be more logging events (likely earlier) that indicate why.

From the Apache James Mime4j website ...

> Apache James Mime4J provides a parser, MimeStreamParser, for e-mail message streams in plain rfc822 and MIME format.

Perhaps your log4j setup is attempting to emit emails on certain events?

The warning message about "too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp" is a consequence of the servlet erroring out and not processing the request body content.  Ignore that warning, and fix the fundamental issue first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I just updated my question by adding the maven dependency setting with the multi-part provider. There it says that the commons-logging is excluded. I'll provide my log4j config, if you require so. Best

Comment: That was the right answere! After adding the maven dependency 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency> everything worked as expected and also the file is beeing uploaded!! Thank you!